# Sequelize finding all unassociated records in many to many relationship

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am having difficult finding all records in my model Course that are not associated with a specific record in my model User (where user_id != some value), through the UserCourse_Join model.

My current function is this:

```
    try {
        const courses = await Course.findAll({
            include: [{
                model: User,
                required: false,
                through: {
                    required: false,
                    model: UserCourse_Join,
                },
                where: {
                    user_id: {
                        [Op.ne]: user_id
                    }
                }
            }],
            subQuery: false
        });
        return courses;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching courses:", error);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

However, no matter what I try I always either get every record of Course, or no record.

My model relationships are defined like this:

```
//Course-User many-to-many,
User.belongsToMany(Course, {
    through: UserCourse_Join,
    foreignKey: "user_id",
    onDelete: CASCADE,
    onUpdate: CASCADE,
});
Course.belongsToMany(User, {
    through: UserCourse_Join,
    foreignKey: "course_id",
    onDelete: CASCADE,
    onUpdate: CASCADE,
});
```

I honestly think this issue is stemming from my lack of understanding the include option. From what I've read it simply creates a left outer or inner join between the models. But I am unsure how the through: option plays into this.

Comment: In order to achieve that you need to use a subquery in the where condition of the main model `Course` that counts how many records with a certain courseId and userid it has and it should be equal to zero.